# How to draw svg line using an object of coordinates?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an object which contains 41 points of x and y coordinates like this:

```
1: {
    x: 325,
    y: 34
},
2: {
    x: 340,
    y: 88
},
3: {
    x: 377,
    y: 36
}
```

Is it possible to extend svg path with javascript every time user clicks on certain coordinates ?

Comment: yes, it is possible, especially when you provide us with something you already tried and a clear description how it should work

Comment: When user clicks on coordinates 2, i need to extend path from coordinates 1 to 2 and so on. It is experimental connecting dots game :) I've tried to use setAttribute("d", ...), but dont't feel that it is a god idea.